# Terminal says is not a directory while jupyter notebook says it is a directory

Tags: bash, dataframe, terminal, oauth, gspread

While authenticating for df2gspread I am receiving this message

```
InvalidClientSecretsError: ('Error opening file', '/Users/comp/.gdrive_private', 'Is a directory', 21)
```

and while I am in my bash terminal I receive this message

```
cd: not a directory: gdrive_private
```

I do not understand what is happening or why it's claiming on but not another. Within my file system I'm not seeing and file that has '.' before gdrive_private so I'm not sure if thats an issue. The credentials are valid as they worked for gspread but df2gspread has different pathing. This project is going to be in my portfolio so hard pathing within itself isn't an option. Any suggestions would help, thanks

Comment: I've found a work around with authentication from another article
 `from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('./FILE_NAME.json', scope)`

Comment: In the first case, you have `.gdrive_private`, which - according to the message - is a directory. In the second case, you have `gdrive_private`, which is not a directory. Two different names - so two different diagnostic messages.